# Nativescript: Failed to allocate a 1553380 byte allocation

Tags: android, angularjs, nativescript

I'm using Nativescript with Angular and the object of the app is to take photos and then send them via email.
I'm using This [GridView](https://github.com/PeterStaev/NativeScript-Grid-View) to display captured images to the user as you can see in the image below:
[image]

Now as you can see this is the virtual emulator and the app works fine but when I try the app on a real device after the third picture I get this error:

```
System.err: com.tns.NativeScriptException: 
System.err: Calling js method onBindViewHolder failed
System.err: Error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 1553380 byte allocation with 57537 free bytes and 56KB until OOM
```

I'm using databinding to bind the photos array in the `GridView` as described in the code:

```
takePicture(){
        camera.takePicture()
            .then((imageAsset) => {
                console.log('Result is an image asset instance');
                // convert ImageAsset to ImageSource
                fromAsset(imageAsset)
                    .then(res => {
                        let base64 = res.toBase64String('png');
                        let newImage = 'data:image/png;base64,'+base64;
                        this.photos.push(newImage);// I get the base64 of the picture and save it in the array
                    })
            })
    }
```

And this is how i'm binding the array in the `GridView`:

```
<GridView [items]="photos" colWidth="30%" rowHeight="100">
            <ng-template let-item="item" let-odd="odd">
                <StackLayout margin="5" borderColor="gray" borderWidth="1" borderRadius="5" verticalAlignment="stretch" class="list-group-item">
                    <Image [src]="item" ></Image>
                </StackLayout>
            </ng-template>
        </GridView>
```

As I said, the app works fine on the emulator no matter how many pictures I take, but when using a real device I get this error after the third picture.
What is the explanation of this behaviour ?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: @Faly yes, please check my question on NativeScript forums:
https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/unable-to-take-many-pictures-with-camera-failed-to-allocate-a-1553380-byte/3820/13

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @Faly you're welcome :), but to be honest I switched to android native >>> hybrid, native way better performance.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the camera plugin, but I think i see a few problems with your code.

1. You take the picture and get an asset.
2. You when load an image-source from it.
3. This image-source is then decoded into a base64 and added to an array.
4. This base64 is then used in the angular template for the src param.

The base64-encoding is a pretty huge string, so it takes of a lot of memory and might be longer than the max string length.

Also you're loading, encoding and decoding the image when you could just load it in template.

**Try this instead:**

1. Push the imageAsset to the photos array
2. use the imageAsset in the template

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did this but I' still facing the same problem, I'm now saving the ImageAsset in the array and I'm using it in the `<Image/>` tag, but still having memory leak.